# Custom color not displaying

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ResourceDictionary` called `MainTheme` it looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor" R="35" G="35" B="35"></Color>
    <Color x:Key="AccentColor" R="227" G="111" B="28"></Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and I have a main window that looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="Elements.WindowsInstaller.Ui.Views.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Elements.WindowsInstaller.Ui.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Style="{StaticResource ShellStyle}"
        Title="Shell" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <Border x:Name="Sidebar" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="65" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"></Border><!-- I have tried StaticResource and DynamicResource here -->
        <ContentControl ></ContentControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Then in the `App.xaml` I have this:

```
   <Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                 <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainTheme.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>

                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Window.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>       
             </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Can someone please tell me why the Sidebar isn't is not changing the background color?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The issue was the color that I set.
It should of been:

```
<Color x:Key="AccentColor" R="227" G="111" B="28" A="255"></Color>
```